# Do unmanaged switches automatically do bonding/multi-link?

Tags: switch, ethernet

If i have 2 cheap unmanaged non-smart consumer level switches such as "Netgear GS308", do they support having 2 cables between them, and effectivly having 2gbit transfer between them? or will an unmanaged non-smart switch such as this, just get confused and not know what to do with the 2 links?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No unmanaged switch will do this. You will create a loop and your network will break.